# How to customize the axis labels, such as 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using python's matplotlib module to draw a graph related to the month. The main data of my graph is concentrated in winter, that is, November, December, January, the data of these months can draw a continuous plane.

however When I plot the 1-12 months of data onto the map, the January data is on the left side of the graph, and the November and December data is on the right side of the graph. The middle of the graph is empty.

I want to seek one way to change the order of the axis labels, from the order of 1-12 to the order of 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5, so the content of my diagram It can be displayed in the middle, not on both sides. Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: The documentation for matplotlib is excellent, with [examples/gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#), [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html), and detailed [API](https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html) docs. Of particular interest to you might be [plotting categorical variables](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-categorical-variables-py)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I'm assuming that your data is currently sorted by where each month falls in the calendar year starting in January.

```
# matplotlib version 3.1.1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

I'll create a sample pandas dataframe based on how you described your dataset.

```
data = {'month': ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                   'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November',
                   'December'],
        'frequency': [1000, 200, 100, 20, 10, 5, 5, 15, 25, 50, 800, 2000]}

monthly = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print(monthly)

        month  frequency
0     January       1000
1    February        200
2       March        100
3       April         20
4         May         10
5        June          5
6        July          5
7      August         15
8   September         25
9     October         50
10   November        800
11   December       2000
```

The above dataset is sorted by calendar year, and will result in January being on the far left hand side of the plot, and November and December on the far right hand side of the plot.

By updating the `month` column to contain categorical values, we can sort the dataset in the way that best fits our needs.

```
# define the sort order
month_sort = ['June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November',
              'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']

# assign categorical values to the column
monthly['month'] = pd.Categorical(monthly['month'], month_sort, ordered=True)

# sort the dataframe by month
monthly.sort_values('month', inplace=True)

print(monthly)

        month  frequency
5        June          5
6        July          5
7      August         15
8   September         25
9     October         50
10   November        800
11   December       2000
0     January       1000
1    February        200
2       March        100
3       April         20
4         May         10
```

Now the dataframe is in our desired sort order, allowing it to be plotted with November, December, and January in the middle.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax.bar(monthly['month'], monthly['frequency'])
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image: bar_plot]

Comment: Dear daronjp, thank you very much for your help. I tried to solve the problem myself some time ago, so I haven't seen your answer in time. Thank you again, your approach has inspired me so that I can optimize my code.